# Write-Ahead Logging and Read-Only mode compatible in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

### Open read-only

I have a sqlite3 file on a filesystem that belongs to a different user than is running the reading process. I want the reading process to be able to read the file in read-only mode, so I'm passing SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY. I would expect that to work. Surely the idea is that read-only mode works on files that we don't want to write to?

When I prepare my first statement I get

> `unable to open database file`

Similarly if I run the `sqlite3` command line tool I get the same result unless I sudo. Which seems to confirm to me that the issue is writeability rather than anything else.

### Journal files

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957778/opening-a-sqlite3-db-on-a-read-only-filesystem-with-a-journal-file) seems to suggest that if there are journal files around then read-only access isn't possible.

Why are there journal files? Because another process is writing the file, my user process is trying to open it in read-only. To do this I am using Write-Ahead Logging, which produces two journal files, `-shm` and `-wal`. True enough, if I stop the writing process and remove the journal files, my user process can open it in read-only mode.

### Incompatibility?

So I have two situations:

- If the file belongs to the writing process and also the read-only process, write-ahead logging enables process A to write and process B to read-only
- If the file belongs to the writing process but does *not* belong to the read-only process, the read-only process is blocked from opening read-only.

How do I achieve both of these? To spell it out, I want:

- Writing process owns database
- Read-only process does not own database
- Read-only process cannot write to database
- Write-ahead logging is enabled on database

Seems like a simple set of requirements, but I can't see an obvious solution.

**EDIT: ** Going by [this documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html#readonly), it looks like this isn't possible. Can you suggest any alternative ways to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes WAL-journaled databases cannot be opened read-only, explicitly or otherwise (i.e. in the case where the database file is read-only to the process).

If you require that the read-only process absolutely not be allowed to modify the database file, then the only thing that comes to mind is that the write process maintains a not WAL-journal additional copy of the database.

Bottom line: to the best of my knowledge, WAL and read-only can't be done.

Comment: This is no longer the case - see the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/wal.html): "...Beginning with version 3.22.0 (2018-01-22), a read-only WAL-mode database file can be opened if the -shm and -wal files already exists or those files can be created or the database is immutable."

Answer (score 0):

I think what the documentation is saying is that the WAL database itself may not be present on a readonly **media**, which does not necessarily mean you cannot use `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY`. In fact, I have successfully opened two connections, a read-write as well as one with SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, both on a WAL sqlite database. These work just fine. I tested an `INSERT` query using the read-only connection and the statement correctly returned an error that the database is read-only.

Just make sure that the database is stored on some media with write-access as a -shm file needs to be created and maintained, and so even a 'ready-only' connection may actually physically write something to disk - which doesn't necessarily mean that it can modify data using SQL.